# Publishing asp.net solution produces uninitialized (empty) database tables

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, azure, publishing

I am using a mostly **unedited** asp.net identity sample which I got from nuget.org by writing this into the package manager console.

`Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Samples -Pre`

My data source is Microsoft SQL Server Database File.
The database file is located in a folder named App_Data.

I have deployed my website along with the database using Visual Studio Express 2013 for Web by downloading the publish profile from Microsoft Azure portal.

The settings used to publish are as follows: (I cannot include images)
File Publish Options
(Checked) Remove additional files at destination
(Checked) Precompile during publishing
(Unchecked) Exclude files from the App_Data folder

Databases
Connection string:

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\***.mdf;Initial Catalog=***;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

(Checked) Use this connection string at runtime
(Checked) Execute Code First Migrations

Locally, the website is working perfectly. The problem only exists on the published website.

The problem is that the table AspNetUsers is empty, the default admin credentials are not added into the table on the published website.

I have tried using this header

```
public class ApplicationDbInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<ApplicationDbContext>
```

But it did not make a difference.

How to fix this problem?

Thank you very much :)

Comment: As far as i know AspNetUsers table will be empty by default it will have data only when a new user is created.Have you migrated data also ?

Comment: @MairajAhmad Thank you for your reply :) The method InitializeIdentityForEF(), which is located in IdentityConfig, should add at least 1 admin when there isn't an admin already. So, AspNetUsers should never be empty. I did not migrate any data, and I believe I should not need to migrate the admin user data if the code was working properly.

Comment: Have you logged exceptions so that you can check where the problem is ?

Comment: does ' (LocalDb)` really works in Azure Web Sites ?!

Comment: @MairajAhmad I have not logged exceptions. Although, I do not think the code is faulty - since it is a mostly an unedited sample -, I am trying to debug remotely.

Comment: @astaykov I think '(LocalDb)' does work because all other database-related operations are fine except for the initialization part.

Comment: This is just to mitigate the problem for those who are interested. The local database can be transferred with the data inside of it to the online database server using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: are you still facing this issue ?

Comment: @SuhasJoshi I was able to reproduce the problem locally and solve it from there. Initializing the database created a deadlock that I think was because I used multiple dbcontexts for the same object. Fixing that eliminated the problem.